# What does 女子が好きな趣味の人 mean here?

Tags: meaning, syntax, sentence

This is an answer for a question from a 腐女子 about whether having their shipping changed ex  a loves a female and b loves another is a source of annoyance or not this is the answer :

腐女子ですが男女カプ成立したりほんのり関係性を示唆してたりしても大好きですよ。
腐カプと公式カプ両方ともかけたら楽しいと思うんですが、どうしてもBL楽しすぎて切り替えられないだけですね。
過去にハマったジャンルでは結婚した男女カプに加えて攻め(人によっては受け)のもう一人男性キャラ加えた三人でのイチャイチャする作品専用のタグまでできてました。
お嫁さんになる女の子が出番が少ないながらも明るく魅力的なキャラで、攻め受けとお嫁さんまとめて幸せになれ〜って言う人が結構いる珍しいジャンルでした。
そこまで行かずとも女性キャラ加えたカプ要素のないほのぼのも好きとか、攻め受けのBLを応援してくれる**女子が好きな趣味の人は結構いるんじゃないでしょうか。**

Comment: Do you understand how the relative clause before that 女子 is working? The sentence means "I think there are quite a few people who loves a girl supportive of seme-uke BL", not "I think there are quite a few people who love girls and supports seme-uke BL".

Answer (score 2):

が marks the object of すき just as in 猫が好き. And the 攻め受け...好きな modifies 趣味.

Perhaps you may be confused around 趣味の人. [趣味](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%B6%A3%E5%91%B3/#jn-106221) here means:

> ２ どういうものに美しさやおもしろさを感じるかという、その人の感覚のあり方。好みの傾向。

For explanation, consider:

- ショートカットの女の子が趣味だ - I like girls with short haircut. (Or, though I don't know if it's correct as English, A girl with short haircut is my type).
- 猫が好きな人 - People who like cats

The sentence in question combines both, meaning people with the tendency of liking girls such that 攻め受け...くれる. It's a bit redundant. ...女子が好きな人 is essentially the same. Literally, が好きな趣味の人 means something like *people whose tendency is liking....*

Then は is the subject/topic marker and 結構いるんじゃないでしょうか means *I guess there are plenty of them*.

Over all the last sentence means something like *Even if no that far (as stated in the preceding sentence), **I guess there are plenty of** people who also like 女性キャラ..ほのぼの or **people who tend to like girls that** 攻め...応援してくれる.*

Comment: does 女性キャラ加えたカプ要素のないほのぼの mean :ほのぼの  where the element of adding a female character to the couple does not exsist ?

Comment: @goldenlight No. 女性キャラ加えた directly modifies ほのぼの. "the couple-less ほのぼの (genre) where there are also female characters".